# Are ngModel and bsValue interchangeable for ngx-bootstrap bsDatePicker?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Both `ngModel` and `bsValue` are used in the [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/5.6.0/#/datepicker#date-initial-state) as ways to set/get the value for `bsDatePicker`. Is the only difference between them that `ngModel` is used with angular forms, or is there more to it than that? Also, is there any reason to use both `ngModel` and `bsValue` on the same element (I'm assuming no)?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker)

> Datepicker and daterangepicker can be used in forms. Keep in mind that
> value of ngModel is Date object for datepicker and array of 2 Date
> objects for daterangepicker

I would agree that they are interchangeable, however as stated. The ngModel is of type Date or 2 Date objects.

So stick to ngModel if you are using the input in a form and bsValue if you aren't.